# Simple capacitor diagram Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I want to draw this diagram:

[image: capacitor diagram]

I wrote the following lines to draw something similar:

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
    \draw (0,0)
    to [polar capacitor, invert, l=$C$, *-*, f=$i$, v_=$v$] (4,0);
\end{circuitikz}
```

and the result is:

[image]

I don't know how to do the following steps:

- To put the plus and minus signs below the dots and aligned with *v*.
- To put the current arrow below the capacitor symbol.

Comment: I will try to answer tomorrow, but if you want such a fine  control on the labels, probably the best option is to draw them separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the last unpublished version of `circuitikz` you can use `voltage shift` (notice that thanks to this post I just fixed a bug) to obtain something like that:

```
\draw (0,0)
to [polar capacitor,  invert, l=$C$, *-*, f=$i$, v_=$v$, voltage shift=.7] (3,0);
```

to move a bit the voltage signs:

[image: capacitance, 1]

but there is no provision for the kind of current arrow you are looking for. In your case, I would build it by hand:

```
\draw (0,-2) coordinate(a)
to[polar capacitor, invert, l=$C$, *-*] ++(3,0);
\path (a) ++(0,-0.8) node{$+$} -- node[midway]{$v$} ++(3,0) node{$-$};
\draw[-Triangle] (a) ++(1,-1.2) -- node[midway, below]{$i$} ++(1,0);
```

[image: capacitance, 2]

Notes:

(1) I used relative movement so that it will be easy to add that to a macro;

(2) Yes, arguably the need to use `invert` here is a bug. But I fear a lot of compatibility problems if I flip it...